# Why does IContainer.IsRegistered(Type serviceType) add registrations?

Tags: autofac

Why does IContainer.IsRegistered(Type serviceType) add registrations?

```
Type serviceType = typeof (string[]);
int rc = container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.Count();
container.IsRegistered(serviceType);
int rc2 = container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.Count();
Assert.AreEqual(rc, rc2);
```

The mentioned behavior could make the following side effect:

```
public class Test
{
      public Entity[] Entities { get; set; }
}
//...
var bldr = new ContainerBuilder();
bldr.RegisterModule<ArraysInjectionGuardModule>();
var container = bldr.Build();
var t = new Test();
container.InjectProperties(t);
Assert.IsNull(t.Entities);
```

Because `container.InjectProperties(...);` invokes `container.IsRegistered(..)` and passes `typeof(Entity[])` as an argument, t.Entities is initialized with an empty array.
I was a bit confused when I discovered this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the mentioned behavior is [by design](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/autofac/VYDnoDjZy6o/-kQga1fQ2GUJ)

Here is a workaround to avoid injection of empty arrays.
It uses reflection so use this approach on your own risk.
Please be aware that it **decreases resolution performance**.
You just need to register the following module:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterModule<ArraysInjectionGuardModule>();

class ArraysInjectionGuardModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Activating += (s, e) =>
        {
            var ts = e.Component.Services.Single() as TypedService;
            if (ts != null && ts.ServiceType.IsArray &&
                !e.Context.IsRegistered(ts.ServiceType.GetElementType()))
            {
                FieldInfo t = e.GetType().GetField("_instance",
                                                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                t.SetValue(e, null);
            }
        };
    }
}
```